# EverNote C# SDK in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, dll, sdk, evernote

It seems the EverNote SDK uses .NET 4 whereas my current project is in .NET 3.5.  I don't think I can simply update the 3.5 to 4 since it may cause issues as I have a large codebase.

I am trying to use the namespaces as provided with the EverNote SDK so that I can connect to EverNote via my application.  Is there anyway to do what I want without having to update to 4.0?  Every time I try to add the .DLLs it says the framework is incompatible.

The C# SDK for EverNote: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-csharp

Comment: I say bite the bullet and update your target framework. I haven't seen much of issues updating several tens of projects, you should be done in a day tops. Deployment for customers may be more of an issue but unless you push them they'd still use punch cards

Comment: @StenPetrov I'd agree, especially since this is a web app, in which case he controls the entire deployment chain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no (direct) way to use a 4.0 assembly from a 3.5 project, by design.

You really either need to move your codebase (at least the main executable, and any libraries which need to reference Evernote) to 4.0.

The only alternative would be to try to backport their codebase to 3.5.  However, that's potentially going to be difficult, especially if they're using 4.0 features.

Comment: Could I create a new solution in .NET 4 and upload to the same webserver (making it relatively transparent to the user)?  Basically, I'm asking:  Can I run 3.5 and 4 on the same server concurrently?

Comment: Would you recommend this over "multi-targeting" or are they kind of the same thing http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/27/multi-targeting-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx ?

Comment: @user1477388 That's a bit of a different animal.  That's allowing you to use VS 2010 to target old frameworks...

Comment: Reed, the http://serverfault.com/questions/269066/can-i-run-net4-applications-within-a-net3-5-website/269074#269074 page says, "then, you will need to configure the site's root to run using the 3.5 framework, and the folder (or virtual directory) where your sub-application resides to run using 4.0."  The site's root already uses .NET 3.5 so I am good there, I think.  **But, how can I configure a specific folder to use .NET 4?**

Comment: I would have to do this in IIS?

Comment: @user1477388 I'd ask in the serverfault answer - I'm no expert in this ;)